# Loopbackjs social login with Facebook

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, cookies, loopbackjs

I have a simple web service and I want to add social login with Facebook and Google using Loopbackjs. 
 
I've already done parts of this editing the example found at this link: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport and following the instructions at this one: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Third-party+login+using+Passport. 
My problem now is that I need to retrieve user information after login, so that every following editing request on the User model can be direct to the owning User entity.

> e.g. The User X want to access to my application:
>
> 1. X request for "example_site_address/auth/facebook";
> 2. X will redirect to "www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=example_site_address/auth/facebook/callback&scope=email&client_id=XXXXXXX";
> 3. After his acceptation, he will redirect to "example_site_address/auth/facebook/callback&scope=email&client_id=XXXXXXX";
> 4. Then he will again redirect to "example_site_address/success_fb", this link should give to the client the User entity with which he is logged in.

Using Google this problem is solved because I could retrieve AccessToken information from the cookies, find the User who's owning that, and then send back it to the client, so he can store the UserId and every a following request could be like on this User. 
Using Facebook I'm not able to do this, because cookies concern login are encrypted.

I'm a really beginner on this kind of application, so it is possible that my strategy is wrong. Could you help me to do this?

Comment: The client is an Ionic app

Comment: [LoopBack Example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) is using a [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) package (see [server/server.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport/blob/master/server/server.js)). Cookies are signed but you have access to them via `req.signedCookies`.

Comment: Thank you @IvanSchwarz! I resolved using `req.signedCookies`

Comment: You are welcome! I've added my comment in a form of an answer - in case you want to close this question by accepting an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LoopBack Example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) is using a [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) package (see [server/server.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport/blob/master/server/server.js)). Cookies are signed but you have an access to them via `req.signedCookies` property.